# How to prevent downloadthis button in Quarto HTML report from jumping to top of page on click?

Tags: html, r, quarto

I have a lengthy Quarto HTML report with several [downloadthis buttons.](https://github.com/fmmattioni/downloadthis) When clicking each button, however, the browser jumps to the top of the screen. I've observed this in both Chrome and Firefox. How do I prevent/suppress this behavior?

[Reproducible `.qmd` gist here.](https://gist.github.com/daranzolin/8f37d90267539094275bca15410cd51c)

**Edit:**

````
---
title: "downloadthis reprex"
format: html
---


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

```{r}
library(downloadthis)
mtcars %>%
  download_this(
    output_name = "mtcars data set",
    output_extension = ".csv",
    button_label = "Download data",
    button_type = "warning",
    has_icon = TRUE,
    icon = "fa fa-save"
  )
```
````

Comment: Hi David! I have added the code from the gist to your question, since it is not that big and because if for some reason, the link to the gist doesn't work anymore, this question would be incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution to this problem is to add the button id (which we need to add by `id` argument of `download_this`) to the download link embedded by `{downloadthis}`.

````
---
title: "downloadthis reprex"
format: html
include-after-body: button.html
---

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

```{r}
library(downloadthis)
mtcars %>%
  download_this(
    output_name = "mtcars data set",
    output_extension = ".csv",
    button_label = "Download data",
    button_type = "warning",
    has_icon = TRUE,
    icon = "fa fa-save",
    id = 'mtcars-btn' # add an id to this button
  )
```
````

**button.html**

```
<style>
  #mtcars-btn:focus,
  #mtcars-btn:active  {
     box-shadow: none !important;
  }
  
  #mtcars-btn:hover {
     transition: 0.2s;
     filter: brightness(0.90);
  }
  
  #mtcars-btn:active {
     filter: brightness(0.80);
}
</style>

<script>
  function add_href() {
    let mtcars_a = document.querySelector("a:has(#mtcars-btn)");
    mtcars_a.href = '#mtcars-btn';
  }
  
  window.onload = add_href;
</script>
```

---

Make sure to place both of the qmd file and `button.html` files in the same directory or even if placed in a different directory, make the appropriate changes in `include-after-body` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @shafee! Your solution works great for my example, so I've marked it as the solution. However, the same jumping behavior returns when the buttons appear on tabs (at least the second tab). I've updated the gist if you're curious: https://gist.github.com/daranzolin/8f37d90267539094275bca15410cd51c

Comment: Interesting, if you hover over the button on the second tab, the #id is missing from the link, unlike the button on the first tab.

Comment: Ah, since I have multiple buttons, I just had to use document.querySelectorAll() and then loop through the 'array' with .forEach(). Solved!

Comment: Oh, I completely missed the part about "multiple buttons", since your example includes only one, but yes the same idea is extendable using loops.

Comment: @DavidRanzolin, you may want to check out quarto shortcode extension [`downloadthis`](https://github.com/shafayetShafee/downloadthis) which makes adding download buttons easier and also accounts for the problem question, so you do not have to use additional javascript. [DISCLAIMER: the extension is made by me : ) ]